# CGAL 3D Function Interpolation

Tags: 3d, interpolation, cgal

In the CGAL manual, it says [here](http://doc.cgal.org/4.4/Interpolation/index.html):

> Scattered data interpolation solves the following problem: given measures of a function on a set of data points, the task is to interpolate this function on an arbitrary query point. More formally, let P={p1,…,pn} be a set of n points in R2 or R3 and Φ be a scalar function defined on the convex hull of P. We assume that the function values are known at the points of P, i.e. to each pi∈P, we associate zi=Φ(pi).

Then it proceeds to show examples, but the closest example to interpolation in **3D** that I find is the example, `Interpolation/surface_neighbor_coordinates_3.cpp`.  As far as I can tell, this only finds the neighbor vertices of a point.

Is there a subsequent step that I can take to find the *interpolated function value* at an arbitrary query point in 3D? (Specifically, over a sphere?)

Comment: Have you found a solution, since mid-July?

Comment: Basically, my solution now is to: 3D Delaunay triangulate, convert convex hull to polyhedron, make a tree of that, then use "closest_point_and_primitive" lookup in the tree, for any queried point.  After that, I do my own spherical triangle area computation using the surrounding 3 neighbors of this point, and weight the three data values based on the percentage of the full spherical area that these subregions occupy.  3D Interpolation.  Made...simple...

Comment: For the knowledge base of Stack Overflow, could you please post a self-answer and accept it?

Answer (score 2):

In the [same page you quote, at the section "3 Interpolation Methods"](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Interpolation/index.html#title12), there is the description of interpolation methods, with two examples. It is probably what you are looking for. You would have to adapt those examples to 3D, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not exactly trivial to transfer the 2D examples to 3D; I would try it this

```
#include <stdexcept>  // std::logic_error
#include <iterator>   // back_inserter
#include <algorithm>  // copy_n
#include <functional> // function<R(A)> 
#include <map>        // map, pair
#include <cmath>      // abs()
#include <string>     // string, stoul  
#include <limits>     // numeric_limits<size_t>::max
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


const long  MIN_SAMPLE_SIZE     = 10;
const long  DEFAULT_SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000;
const long  MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE     = 100000;

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_3.h>
#include <CGAL/natural_neighbor_coordinates_3.h>
#include <CGAL/interpolation_functions.h>
#include <CGAL/surface_neighbor_coordinates_3.h>
///@TODO check if using Delaunay tesselation could make it faster
//#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>

using Kernel             = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using real_t             = Kernel::FT;
using point3_t           = Kernel::Point_3;
using vec3_t             = Kernel::Vector_3;
using value_map_t        = std::map<point3_t, real_t, Kernel::Less_xyz_3>;
using value_access_t     = CGAL::Data_access<value_map_t>;
using distance_vec_t     = std::vector<std::pair<point3_t, real_t>>;


using ScalarR3Field      = std::function<real_t(point3_t)>;

const ScalarR3Field maxN = [] (const point3_t& p) {
    std::vector<real_t> v {
        std::abs(p.x()),
        std::abs(p.y()),
        std::abs(p.z())
    };
    return *std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
    //return std::max(v.begin(), v.end());
};

const ScalarR3Field l1N = [] (const point3_t& p) {
    return std::abs(p.x()) +
        std::abs(p.y()) +
        std::abs(p.z());
};


std::map<std::string, ScalarR3Field> TESTS {
    {"maximum norm", maxN},
    {"l_1 norm",  l1N}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto sample_size = DEFAULT_SAMPLE_SIZE; 

    if (argc > 1) {
        try {
            auto val = std::stol(argv[1]);
            if (val < MIN_SAMPLE_SIZE) {
                throw std::logic_error("sample size suppplied is too small");
            } else if (val > MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE) {
                throw std::logic_error("sample size suppplied is too large");
            }
            sample_size = val;
        } catch (const std::logic_error& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << ";"
                      << " using default sample size of "
                      << (sample_size = DEFAULT_SAMPLE_SIZE) 
                      << "." << std::endl;  
        } // try/catch for argv[1] conversion 
    } // if (argc > 1) 

    std::vector<point3_t> points;
    points.reserve(sample_size);

    CGAL::Random_points_on_sphere_3<point3_t> gen (1.0);
    std::copy_n(gen, sample_size, std::back_inserter(points));

    auto point  = *(++gen);
    auto vec    = point - CGAL::ORIGIN;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto& test : TESTS) {
        value_map_t F;
        auto& f = test.second;

        for (auto& p: points)
            F.emplace(std::make_pair(p, f(p)));

        distance_vec_t coords;

        auto triple =  CGAL::surface_neighbor_coordinates_3(
                           points.begin(), points.end(),
                           point, vec,
                           std::back_inserter(coords),
                           Kernel()
                       );

        auto intp   =  CGAL::linear_interpolation(
                                coords.begin(), coords.end(),
                                triple.second,
                                value_access_t(F)
                       );

        auto nomn   = f(point); 

        std::cout   << test.first << "([" << point << "])"
                    << "\tnominal: "      << nomn
                    << "\tinterpolated: " << intp 
                    << "\t\tΔ=" << (intp-nomn)*real_t(100.0)/nomn 
                    << "%\n";
    } // for (auto& test : TESTS)

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // int main
```

way; doesn't seem too far off:

./cgal_test 10000

```
l_1 norm([-0.689748 -0.39429 -0.607274])    nominal: 1.69131    interpolated: 1.69079       Δ=-0.0309701%
maximum norm([-0.689748 -0.39429 -0.607274])    nominal: 0.689748   interpolated: 0.689535      Δ=-0.0309701%
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions!  I will look at it, I had given up on the problem because I was under a time-constraint and had to move on.